# Cancancan roles_mask not mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

Using the most basic implementation of cancancan and feel like I'm going crazy.

Here's what's in my user model

```
 ROLES = %i[admin regular reporter]

  # Roles logic to covert string above to/from integers
  def roles=(roles)
    roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject do |r|
      ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
    end
  end

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.include?(role)
  end
```

user with 1 is showing role :admin

user with 2 is showing role :regular

but user with 3 is showing role [:admin, :regular]

can't figure it out to save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, 3 is the correct `roles_mask` for `[:admin, :regular]`.

If you are trying to set the `User` to a `reporter`, it would not be 3 but actually 4.

This is because the `roles=` method, with the most basic usage, converts your `ROLES` array to:

`ROLES_MAP = [1, 2, 4]`

(...and therefore allows multiple roles to be combined simply by adding the numbers together)

But, if you want to set a User object as a reporter, you should use:

: `@user.roles = "reporter"`

and best not to set `roles_mask` directly, like this:

: `@user.roles_mask = 4`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I eventually figured that out, by using the method you suggest of setting to the symbol, not the roles_mask. I'm curious as to why it converts the array to 1, 2, 4? I'm assuming an additional role would be a roles_mask of 8? Any reason why this is the typical solution?

Comment: Yes, for that particular code you are using, it allows you to give the user multiple roles all stored in one single number value, stored as one field in a database table I guess.

Comment: (If you just want one role per user, you could remove all the code there and just have a plain old indexed array.)